# Android Studio start new activity from progress bar

Tags: android

I created a progress and i want it to take the user to the next screen when it is done loading . I put some code in to make it go to the next screen when the progress bar is done loading but it's not working . I tried clarifying the second activity in the android manifest file but it still doesn't go to that page when it's done loading. This is the code that i wrote . If someone can give me proper code or tell me if i did something wrong , I would appreciate it very very much thanks !

Mainactivity :

```
package com.example.brandon.territories;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private ImageView ImageView;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Long operation by thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 5;
                //Update progress bar with completion of operation
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
                    //Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar
{
    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress)
    {
        super.setProgress(progress);
        if(progress == this.getMax())
        {
            //Do stuff when progress is max
            Intent intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items
    //to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Android manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.brandon.territories" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error

```
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

`MyProgressBar` is never being used, therefore the fancy new `setProgress` method that starts `SecondActivity` is never called. You should cast to `MyProgressBar` instead if you are using your new class in XML as well. you could also try adding `MyProgressBar` to your layout through code before starting the thread.

Comment: I'm getting a red line under class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar

Comment: "red line" doesn't say anything useful. Could you post any errors or warnings that you get?

Comment: Error:(48, 12) error: no suitable constructor found for ProgressBar()
constructor ProgressBar.ProgressBar(Context,AttributeSet,int,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ProgressBar.ProgressBar(Context,AttributeSet,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ProgressBar.ProgressBar(Context,AttributeSet) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor ProgressBar.ProgressBar(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: That's what in message log .

Comment: `MyProgressBar` lacks a Constructor. You should implement the constructors from the superclass. If you are using Android Studio, place your cursor on the red line and press Alt + Enter and select "Create constructor matching super" and in the new window select all the available choices.

Comment: i already did that but it still doesn't work .  But i'll try to select all the choices

Comment: public progressBar(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

Comment: You should have included all. I think that you need at least 2 constructors for a `View` to work .

Comment: i don't know what to put for that . SecondActivity ?

Comment: try this one `MyProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){super(context, attrs);}` next to `public MyProgressBar(Context context) { super(context); }`  for more information about `ProgressBar`'s constructor read the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: So put both constructors  ??

Comment: yes, I don't remember which where the important ones, but keep adding until you can compile